# How to add an OnClick event for an Android custom View

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two images moving across the screen, one is a ball and one is a man.
What I want to happen is when the user touches the image of the man, the ball drops.

My problem is I cannot seem to add an onclick/ontouch event and get it to work.

I'm not implementing it properly, can anyone help please?

I have included the 3 classes below. Greg is the man and the ball is named ball :)

TestAnimationActivity.java

```
 package com.test.firstAnimation;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class TestAnimationActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new MyAnimationView(this));
       }
    }
```

Sprite.java

```
package com.test.firstAnimation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Sprite extends View implements OnClickListener{

     private static int gregCoordX = 410; // the x coordinate at the canvas for greg
     private Bitmap img; // the image of Greg
     private Bitmap img2; // the image of pointer 
     private static int gregCoordY = 125; // the y coordinate at the canvas for greg
     private static int pointCoordX = 10;
     private static int pointCoordY = 10;
     private static int count = 1;
     private static int ballSpeed = 25;
     private static boolean goingRight = false;
     private static boolean goingLeft = true;
     private static boolean pointerGoingRight = false;
     private static boolean pointerGoingLeft = true;


    public Sprite(Context context, int drawable) {

        super(context);

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawable);
        img2 = (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawable));
        count++;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    void setX(int newValue) {
        gregCoordX = newValue;
    }

    public static int getX() {
        return gregCoordX;
    }

    public static int getY() {
        return gregCoordY;
    }

    public static int getBX() {
        return pointCoordX;
    }

    public static int getBY() {
        return pointCoordY;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return img;
    }

    public Bitmap getImg2() {
        return img2;
    }

    public static void dropBall()
    {
        pointCoordY++;
    }

    public static void moveBall(int x) {

           // check the borders
            //if more than ten go right
            //if ten go left
            //if more than 250 go left
            if (x <= 10 && pointerGoingLeft)
            {
            pointCoordX = pointCoordX + ballSpeed;
            pointerGoingRight = true;
            pointerGoingLeft = false;
            }
            else if (x >= 410 && pointerGoingRight)
            {
                pointCoordX = pointCoordX - ballSpeed;
                pointerGoingLeft = true;
                pointerGoingRight = false;
            }
            else if (pointerGoingRight)
                pointCoordX = pointCoordX + ballSpeed;
            else
                pointCoordX = pointCoordX - ballSpeed;

            if(MyAnimationView.ballDropping == true)
            {
                while (pointCoordY<gregCoordY)
                    dropBall();
            }
    }

    public static void moveGreg(int x) {

        if (x <= 10 && goingLeft)
        {
        gregCoordX = gregCoordX + count;
        goingRight = true;
        goingLeft = false;
        }
        else if (x >= 410 && goingRight)
        {
        gregCoordX = gregCoordX - count;
        goingLeft = true;
        goingRight = false;
        }
        else if (goingRight)
        gregCoordX = gregCoordX + count;
        else
        gregCoordX = gregCoordX - count;
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        dropBall();
    }
}
```

MyAnimationView.java

```
package com.test.firstAnimation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.View;

public class MyAnimationView extends View{

    private Sprite greg;
    private Sprite ball;
    private int xCoOr;
    private int ballXCoOr;
    public static boolean ballDropping;

    public MyAnimationView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        ballDropping = false;
        greg = new Sprite(context,R.drawable.greg);
        ball = new Sprite(context, R.drawable.ball);

        OnClickListener gregClicked = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ballDropping = true;
            }
        };
        greg.setOnClickListener(gregClicked);
        }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

     canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);                                   //white background      

     ballXCoOr = Sprite.getBX();  
     xCoOr = Sprite.getX();
     Sprite.moveGreg(xCoOr);                                         //move ball left or right depending
     Sprite.moveBall(ballXCoOr);

     if(ballDropping == true)
     {
         Sprite.dropBall();
     }

     canvas.drawBitmap(greg.getBitmap(), xCoOr, Sprite.getY(), null);
     canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ballXCoOr, Sprite.getBY(), null);
     invalidate();
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance, I've been stuck for days!

Ben

Comment: I apologise for the poor formatting, this is my first post :)

Comment: I don't think your code works because the Sprite views aren't subviews of MyAnimationView. The onClick listener doesn't fire because the Views are never used - you simply read out their Bitmaps and draw those in onDraw. I'd post this as an answer but it is the problem, not the solution.

Comment: look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17978891/779408

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    float touched_x, touched_y;
    boolean touched = false;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        touchCounter++;
        touched_x = event.getX();
        touched_y = event.getY();

        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touched = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touched = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touched = false;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touched = false;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            touched = false;
            break;
        default:
        }
        return true; // processed
    }
```

Then;

```
    if (touched) {
        //control here
    }
```

touched_x, touched_y are coordinates of the point that is clicked on the screen. You can compare Greg's coordinates and these coordinates. If same, then do what you wanna do.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class CustomView extends View implements OnClickListener {

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Do whatever you need to
    }

}
```